# How to map newsequentialid with NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, filetable

I am using SQL Server FileTable with NHibernate.

On insert, NHibernate will call a stored procedure that inserts a record into the FileTable. The problem I have is that the Id (`stream_id`) column in the FileTable is generated by SQL Server on insert. It is generated by the default constraint `newsequentialid()`.

How can I return that id from my stored procedure and map it to id property of my entity?

**Update:**

Regarding the other question: [NHibernate use stored procedure OR mapping][1]
This is not applicable here. I am using a stored procedure to insert an entity. That stored procedure must return an Id of type Guid that the database has generated at insert time. I want NHibernate to map this id to the entity.

I need something like Generators.TriggerIdentity but for Guid instead of Int.

**Update2:**

I managed to populate my Entity.Id by setting it's Id Generating strategy to 'Native' and selecting a return value from the stored procedure. But this breaks the transaction because to get the Id it needs to go to the database and do an insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by changing the Id Generator to Generators.Native.
Then i had to return the inserted id from the stored procedure.